# 412 no matching index found Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have the following error:

> 412 no matching index found. recommended index is: 
> - kind: monthly_report
>   properties:
>   - name: belongs_to 
>   - name: date_added

I am using Python 3.5, the datastore, and a remote Django project which is accessing the datastore through google-cloud API (google-cloud==0.24.0).

I ran the commands:

```
google cloud datastore cleanup-indexes index.yaml
google cloud datastore create-indexes index.yaml
```

The indexes are created:

**index.yaml:**

```
indexes:

- kind: history
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: date_added
    direction: asc
  - name: address
    direction: asc

- kind: payment
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: date_added
    direction: asc
  - name: belongs_to
  - name: order

- kind: monthly_report
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: date_added
    direction: asc
  - name: status
  - name: belongs_to
    direction: asc
```

I make a query on kind `payment` with filters on `date_added` and `belongs_to`. It works.

However, in the same method, I make a query on kind `monthly_report` with filters on `date_added` and `belongs to`, and I get the error above.

What is the issue?

**Update:**

If I filter for one name it works, for multiple names it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the order counts, so I changed this:

```
- kind: monthly_report
  properties:
  - name: belongs_to
  - name: date_added
```

to this:

```
- kind: monthly_report
  properties:
  - name: date_added
  - name: belongs_to
```

Answer (score 1):

Google app engine's datastore automatically creates indices whenever you make a query involving all the filters you used. It stores your table data in that index for you so that it serves it quickly. So, whenever you deploy you have update the new indices.

If you are deploying using appcfg then, 
`appcfg.py -A <project-name> update_indexes .`

Here the `.` is the path of your `index.yaml` file.

Whenever you get no matching index found or `NeedIndexError` or missing index error, the error also suggests which index is missing. So, you just have to put that suggested index into your `index.yaml` file and update your indices using above command.

In this case, add this missing index to `index.yaml` file.

```
- kind: monthly_report
  properties:
  - name: belongs_to
  - name: date_added
```

I hope this helps.  For more information [Datastore Indices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Using_Automatic_Index_Configuration)

Comment: I already run in the gcloud shell the command ```gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes``` and  ```gcloud datastore create-indexes index.yaml```.

Comment: After running the second command in above comment, it must have created indices. To that `index.yaml` file, just add the above mentioned missing index and redeploy.

Comment: there is no missing index

Comment: Your question itself is saying that you are getting missing index error. What is the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: This is my problem, in the question I post the my index.yaml file, there is kind ```monthly_report```, and properties ```belongs_to``` and ```date_added```.I make a query on kind ```payment``` with filters on ```date_added``` and ```belongs_to```. Is working.

In the same method I make a query on kind ```monthly_report``` with filters on ```date_added``` and ```belongs to```, and I get the error above.

Comment: Understood. You are getting the data in case of `Payment` table query because you have index required to serve that query. See the index of kind `Payment` above. In a similar way, append the missing index which I have also written in my answer above and deploy your code. And run the `appcfg.py -A <project-name> update_indexes <path to index.yaml file>` command. This will solve the problem.